# How to make an inline-block element span the rest of the text line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the situation:

[image: situation]

I have a container (`div` in the picture) that has a single child - the `span`. I'd like to add a second child so that it would take up the entire red space in the picture.

Of course, if the span would only take one line, this could have been done easily with flexbox. But in the case of a line break like in the picture, "flex"-ing the container causes all the lines to jump to the side and free up space for the second child, which is not what I want.

If what I'm trying to achieve is not possible with CSS, is there a way to access the right bound of the last line of the text? Computing the width with JS is a suitable option, I only need a way to tell how much space in the line is already taken.

**UPD:**
The second element will be an `input`. That's the reason why `text-align: justify` won't do.

Here's the code:

```css
div {border: 1px dotted black; width: 400px}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>lorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis</span>
  <input >
</div>
```

Comment: maybe looking for `text-align:justify` ? if not consider adding your code

Comment: so you want the input to always fill the space there ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif exactly. I want it to reach the right edge of the container `div`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with CSS alone. If was a styling thing then yes but an actual element...uh uh. Interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this in JavaScript, assuming the second child has `id="second"`:

```
var secondElement = document.getElementById('second');
var parentWidth = secondElement.parentElement.offsetWidth;
secondElement.style.width = parentWidth - secondElement.offsetLeft + 'px';
```

This will compute the width dynamically by subtracting the left offset of the second element from its parent's width.

```js
function computeWidth() {
  var secondElement = document.getElementById('second');
  var parentWidth = secondElement.parentElement.offsetWidth;
  secondElement.style.width = (parentWidth - secondElement.offsetLeft - 5) + 'px';
  // The -5 part here is adjustable, see what value fits you
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = computeWidth;
```

```css
div {border: 1px dotted black; width: 500px}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>lorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam</span>
  <input id="second" />
</div>
<button>Compute width</button>
```